# Android NDK r19 could not find standard C++ header #include<string>,# include <vector> during compilation by Android studio 3.3.1 Cmake

Tags: android, android-ndk

I could not understand why the Android NDK complain that standard c++ header such string , vector could not be found during Cmake gradle compilation execute by Android studio  3.3.1

Comment: You have a `.c` file that `include`s a header that contains C++ code. I'm not sure how you expected that to work without the use of `#ifdef __cplusplus` or something similar.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that(?). If you want your `JNIEXPORT`ed functions to be in a .cpp file, then put them in a .cpp file. I don't see how Android Studio is to blame.

Answer (score 2):

Change the suffix of your `native.lib.c` jni file to `.cpp`